# Python how to access dataclass properties in list of dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Using python 3.10.4

Hi all, I'm putting together a script where I'm reading a yaml file with k8s cluster info, and I'd like to treat the loaded yaml as dataclasses so I can reference them with `.` properties.

Example yaml:

```
account: 12345
clusters:
  - name: cluster_1
    endpoint: https://cluster_2
    certificate: abcdef
  - name: cluster_1
    endpoint: https://cluster_2
    certificate: abcdef
```

And here's my script for loading and accessing it:

```
import yaml
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class ClusterInfo:
    _name: str
    _endpoint: str
    _certificate: str

@dataclass
class AWSInfo:
    _account: int
    _clusters: list[ClusterInfo]


clusters = yaml.safe_load(open('D:\git\clusters.yml', 'r'))
a = AWSInfo(
  _account=clusters['account'],
  _clusters=clusters['clusters']
)
print(a._account) #prints 12345
print(a._clusters) #prints the dict of both clusters
print(a._clusters[0]) #prints the dict of the first cluster

#These prints fails with AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_endpoint'
print(a._clusters[0]._endpoint)
for c in a._clusters:
    print(c._endpoint)
```

So my question is: What am I doing wrong on the last prints? How can I access the properties of each member in a dataclass array of dataclass objects?

Comment: `a._clusters` is a list of dictionaries, not a list of `ClusterInfo` objects.

Comment: You need to convert `clusters['clusters']` into a list of `ClusterInfo` when you call `AWSInfo()`.

Comment: it's very important to understand, a "dataclass" is *not a type*. `dataclasses.dataclass` is a code generator which results in a normal class, which creates normal instances.

Comment: As an aside, why is every attribute prepended with a single underscore??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I saw that on another dataclass example, and I believe it's to prevent accidentally naming a property after a built in one.

Comment: No! Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataclasses` module doesn't provide built-in support for this use case, i.e. loading YAML data to a nested class model.

In such a scenario, I would turn to a *ser/de* library such as [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), which provides OOTB support for (de)serializing YAML data, via the [`PyYAML`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) library.

> *Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintener of this library.

#### Step 1: Generate a Dataclass Model

*Note*: I will likely need to make this step easier for generating a dataclass model for YAML data. Perhaps worth creating an issue to look into as time allows. Ideally, usage is from the CLI, however since we have YAML data, it is tricky, because the utility tool expects JSON.

So easiest to do this in Python itself, for now:

```py
from json import dumps

# pip install PyYAML dataclass-wizard
from yaml import safe_load
from dataclass_wizard.wizard_cli import PyCodeGenerator

yaml_string = """
account: 12345
clusters:
  - name: cluster_1
    endpoint: https://cluster_2
    certificate: abcdef
  - name: cluster_1
    endpoint: https://cluster_2
    certificate: abcdef
"""

py_code = PyCodeGenerator(experimental=True, file_contents=dumps(safe_load(yaml_string))).py_code
print(py_code)
```

Prints:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class Data(JSONWizard):
    """
    Data dataclass

    """
    account: int
    clusters: list[Cluster]


@dataclass
class Cluster:
    """
    Cluster dataclass

    """
    name: str
    endpoint: str
    certificate: str
```

#### Step 2: Use Generated Dataclass Model, alongside [`YAMLWizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/wizard_mixins.html#yamlwizard)

Contents of `my_file.yml`:

```yaml
account: 12345
clusters:
  - name: cluster_1
    endpoint: https://cluster_5
    certificate: abcdef
  - name: cluster_2
    endpoint: https://cluster_7
    certificate: xyz
```

Python code:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from pprint import pprint

from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class Data(YAMLWizard):
    account: int
    clusters: list[Cluster]


@dataclass
class Cluster:
    name: str
    endpoint: str
    certificate: str


data = Data.from_yaml_file('./my_file.yml')
pprint(data)
for c in data.clusters:
    print(c.endpoint)
```

Result:

```py
Data(account=12345,
     clusters=[Cluster(name='cluster_1',
                       endpoint='https://cluster_5',
                       certificate='abcdef'),
               Cluster(name='cluster_2',
                       endpoint='https://cluster_7',
                       certificate='xyz')])
https://cluster_5
https://cluster_7
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this was a perfect solve!

Comment: no worries! glad it was helpful in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar points out in a comment, even though you have correctly typed the `_clusters` key in your `AWSInfo` dataclass...

```
@dataclass
class AWSInfo:
    _account: int
    _clusters: list[ClusterInfo]
```

...the `dataclasses` module isn't smart enough to automatically convert the members of the `clusters` list in in your input data into the appropriate data type. If you use a more comprehensive data model library like [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/), things will work like you expect:

```
import yaml
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ClusterInfo(BaseModel):
    name: str
    endpoint: str
    certificate: str

class AWSInfo(BaseModel):
    account: int
    clusters: list[ClusterInfo]


with open('clusters.yml', 'r') as fd:
    clusters = yaml.safe_load(fd)
a = AWSInfo(**clusters)

print(a.account) #prints 12345
print(a.clusters) #prints the dict of both clusters
print(a.clusters[0]) #prints the dict of the first cluster

#These prints fails with AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_endpoint'
print(a.clusters[0].endpoint)
for c in a.clusters:
    print(c.endpoint)
```

Running the above code (with your sample input) produces:

```
12345
[ClusterInfo(name='cluster_1', endpoint='https://cluster_2', certificate='abcdef'), ClusterInfo(name='cluster_1', endpoint='https://cluster_2', certificate='abcdef')]
name='cluster_1' endpoint='https://cluster_2' certificate='abcdef'
https://cluster_2
https://cluster_2
https://cluster_2
```

Comment: "isn't smart enough" -> "outside the scope of"

Comment: I think the behavior violates the "principle of least surprise", so we will just have to differ on that point.

Comment: @larsks thank you for showing me what I did wrong. I changed the code and it worked according to your suggestion, but the other answer about datawizards I ended up using just because it was more natively built to do what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the help!